# Bind all methods to 'this'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an IIFE with some methods defined in it, some are public and some are not.

in a lot of the functions (including the private ones) i use the 'this' keyword, so obviously to make sure i'm in the right context, I need to use the `.call(this)` method. Is there a way to bind all functions inside the IIFE to the correct context, without having to use `call()`?

Defining `var self=this` is not an option since it messes up Knockout context.

```
ko.utils.extend(SingleSelectDropdownViewModel.prototype, (function () {
            var STRINGS = {
                All: l10n('All')
            };
        //Public Functions
        var init = function (params) {

            this.selectedValue = params.selectedValue;
            this.title = ko.observable();

            this.items = params.items;
            this.menuOpen = ko.observable(false);

            //would like to avoid using call and just use _setTitle()
            _setTitle.call(this);
        },

        ...
        //Private Functions
        _setTitle = function(){
            if (ko.unwrap(this.selectedValue)){
                var i = util.index(this.items(),ko.unwrap(this.selectedValue),'id');
                i = i > -1 ? i : 0;
                this.title(this.items()[i].text);
            }
            else {
                this.title(this.items()[0].text);
            }

        },


        _hideMenu = function(){
            this.menuOpen(false);
        },


        ...
        return {
            init: init
        };

    })());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you stick to only using `this` in functions that are actually methods of your object, and using function parameters the rest of the time. If you do so, your code becomes:

```
ko.utils.extend(SingleSelectDropdownViewModel.prototype, (function () {
    var STRINGS = {
        All: l10n('All')
    };
    //Public Functions
    var init = function (params) {

        this.selectedValue = params.selectedValue;
        this.title = ko.observable();

        this.items = params.items;
        this.menuOpen = ko.observable(false);

        //would like to avoid using call and just use _setTitle()
        _setTitle(this);
    },

    ...
    //Private Functions
    _setTitle = function (obj) {
        if (ko.unwrap(obj.selectedValue)){
            var i = util.index(obj.items(),ko.unwrap(obj.selectedValue),'id');
            i = i > -1 ? i : 0;
            obj.title(obj.items()[i].text);
        }
        else {
            obj.title(obj.items()[0].text);
        }
    },


    _hideMenu = function(obj){
        obj.menuOpen(false);
    },


    ...
    return {
        init: init
    };

})());
```